# Memory leaks/spike while parsing pdf images to be sent to ftp

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, pdfbox, heap-memory

I have a PDF document of 20MB and 9 pages which I am trying to convert to image and FTP them, I am using pdfBox (2.0.16 version) and the below logic is causing heavy spike in heap memory from less than 500 MB all the way to 2000MB. I followed the faq of pdf box (https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#outofmemoryrrror) but as of now it didn't help. I upgraded from current 2.0.16 version to 2.0.20 but that also didn't resolve the issue. Any pointers on what is wrong will be incredibly helpful for me to fix this issue. Memory increase of 1500 MB for a 20 MB file is a lot and I am running my app via tomcat and its crashing the server.

P.S: Please let me know if there is any other thing I could do or any more details.

**Code:**

```
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile,
                    MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
                PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
                PDPageTree pdPageTree =  document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
                int pageNumber = 1;
                strPdfFileName = strPdfFileName.replace(" ", "_"); 
                UploadFileBuilder objUploadFileBuilder;
                BufferedImage image;
                File outputFile;
                for (int i = 0; i < pdPageTree.getCount(); i++) {
                    strUploadFileName = new StringBuilder(strPdfFileName);
                    strUploadFileName.append("_").append(pageNumber).append(".png");
                    image = renderer.renderImage(pageNumber-1);
                    outputFile = new File(strPdfFilePath + File.separator + strPdfFileName +"_"+ pageNumber +".png");
                    LOGGER.debug("Image Created ----> {}", outputFile.getName());
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFile);
                    image.flush();
                    objUploadFileBuilder=new UploadFileBuilder();
                    objUploadFileBuilder.on(strUploadFileName.toString()).path(strFtpDir.toString()).withData(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    lstUploadFileBuilder.add(objUploadFileBuilder);
                    strFileNameList.add(strUploadFileName.toString());
                    pageNumber++;
                }


                document.close();
                UploadFileBuilder.execute(lstUploadFileBuilder);
```

[image]

Edit1: Stack trace of the issue, Also made change to flush the image.

[image: Eclipse Memory analyzer]

Edit2: current -XMX setting (max memory allocation pool of JVM was 512m) and I am using java 1.8.0_91

Comment: Can you share the PDF? One additional thing you can try is to call renderer.setSubsamplingAllowed(true).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr sorry its 20MB , I can't upload but this is one of the PDF I have tested from open internet https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_FlightPlan.pdf I will try the option you suggested.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr upon trying the option I still see the memory spike.  I can't upload but this is one of the PDF I have tested from open internet https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_FlightPlan.pdf

Comment: I was able to run PDFToImage with -Xmx1g with that file, on jdk1.8.0_252 (amazon corretto). Make sure you are using the latest jdk, especially when using jdk8. Also jdk11 and 14 use less memory. Try also adding "image.dispose()" when done with the image.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Increasing -Xmx is an option but I am afraid if the memory spikes are so drastic up by almost 1000 MB for a 20 MB file how it would react to another file say 100 MB. In any case the memory spike is too big just for 20 MB file conversion.

Comment: I just did a test with -Xmx256m successfully. You mention you are using "jdk8". Which jdk8? It should be the latest.

Comment: Currently we are using jdk1.8.0_91. If that is a concern can upgrade to 1.8.0_252 and check.

Comment: Yes it is a concern. Bugs get fixed (and this includes memory leaks), and security leaks get fixed. And make sure that tomcat is updated too (if applicable). Here's an example of what happens when you don't update software: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Equifax_data_breach

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

(1) Add the following dependency to your maven project (or manually if you don't use maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gredler</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk9-png-writer-backport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(2) Change your conversion code to use the backportedWriter and a FileCacheImageOutputStream:

```
private static void convertMethod2(File pdf) {
        try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            List<String> base64DocumentPages = new ArrayList<>();               

            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
                
                FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream(strPdfFilePath + File.separator + strPdfFileName +"_"+ pageNumber +".png"););
                PNGImageWriterBackport writer = chosePngWriter();
            
                if(writer!=null) {
                    try (ImageOutputStream stream = new FileCacheImageOutputStream(baos,null)) {
                        writer.setOutput(stream);
                        writer.write(null,new IIOImage(bim, null, null), getImageParams(writer));
                    }
                    finally {
                        writer.dispose();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.err.println("PNGImageWriterBackport not found! Aborting");
                }
                //do what you need to do
            }
            document.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
    
    private static PNGImageWriterBackport chosePngWriter() {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriters = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
        
        ImageWriter writer = null;
        while(imageWriters.hasNext()) {
        
            writer = imageWriters.next();
            if (writer instanceof PNGImageWriterBackport) {
                return (PNGImageWriterBackport)writer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    private static ImageWriteParam getImageParams(PNGImageWriterBackport writer) {
        ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        //set compression mode which wasn't possible before
        writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        //0.0f highest compression, slowest
        //1.0f lowest compression, fastest
        writeParam.setCompressionQuality(0.86f);
        
        return writeParam;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this option and from the visual vm I still see the original spike I got from 300 MB to around to 1500 MB. I have a hard limit on xmx as 512 mb and with just around 50 mb files its spiking the heap so much that my tomcat is crashing.